# jquery .hover() outFunction flashing bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a website with my friends for a class assignment but, for some reason, the `outFunction` part of my hover function is acting very strangely. When the mouse enters the element, this grey, `div` square fades in `.fadeIn()` in the background but then immediately fades out `.fadeOut()` even though that part is only supposed to come after the person is not hovering over the element anymore. And then, it starts to fade in again and then out, and so on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hover").hide()
  var topic_list = ["WHAT IS A HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARD?", "NATURAL DISASTERS", "OUR IDEAS", "CREDITS AND REFERENCES"];
  var topic_list_id = ["WHAT_IS_A_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARD", "NATURAL_DISASTERS", "OUR_IDEAS", "CREDITS_AND_REFERENCES"];
  for (var i in topic_list) {
    var element = document.createElement("h6");
    var node = document.createTextNode(topic_list[i]);
    $(element).append(node);
    $(header).append(element);
    element.className = "topics";
    element.id = topic_list_id[i];
  }

  $(".topics").hover(function() {
    var x = $(this).position();
    $("#hover").css({
      "left": x.left,
      "width": $(this).outerWidth(true),
      "height": $(this).outerHeight(true)
    });
    $("#hover").fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $("#hover").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
#hover {
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0.25;
  left: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <div id="hover">
  </div>
</header>
```

What's wrong, because I read up on the `.hover()` function of jQuery and I'm pretty sure that it isn't supposed to work like this.

Comment: can you create  a working demo?

Comment: What's the hover for by the way? Do you want to highlight the h6 tag? Or you have a separate background for each of those?

Comment: **1-** With `z-index: 2;` on `#hover`, you can have the `#hover` element in between the hovered `.topics` element and the mouse... That triggers the mouseleave callback and make it flash endlessly... ;) **2-** I agree with the others who say this background animation you attempt to achive should not be done that way. It's over complicated and creates too many issues... like if the user hovers quickly more than on `h6`... All the events are fired, creating the flahy effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hover div has an index greater than your h6 or topics. Which is why when **your hover div appears on the top**, you're not hovering the .topic anymore because it's under the hover div. You need to **set the z-index for hover div** to something below the index of the .topics, in this case **-1.**

**The .topics also use margin which isn't counted as hover.** You could use padding instead.

I prepared 2 snippets;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hover").hide()
  var topic_list = ["WHAT IS A HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARD?", "NATURAL DISASTERS", "OUR IDEAS", "CREDITS AND REFERENCES"];
  var topic_list_id = ["WHAT_IS_A_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARD", "NATURAL_DISASTERS", "OUR_IDEAS", "CREDITS_AND_REFERENCES"];
  for (var i in topic_list) {
    var element = document.createElement("h6");
    var node = document.createTextNode(topic_list[i]);
    $(element).append(node);
    $(header).append(element);
    element.className = "topics";
    element.id = topic_list_id[i];
  }

  $(".topics").hover(function() {
    var x = $(this).position();

    $("#hover").css({
      "top": x.top,
      "bottom": x.bottom,
      "left": x.left,
      "width": $(this).outerWidth(true),
      "height": $(this).outerHeight(true)
    });

    $("#hover").fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $("#hover").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
#hover {
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0.25;
  left: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}

h6 {
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <div id="hover">
  </div>
</header>
```

**Alternatively**, you could just use CSS if you really just want to highlight the element. Modify the element's **css transition property for the fade effect.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hover").hide()
  var topic_list = ["WHAT IS A HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARD?", "NATURAL DISASTERS", "OUR IDEAS", "CREDITS AND REFERENCES"];
  var topic_list_id = ["WHAT_IS_A_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARD", "NATURAL_DISASTERS", "OUR_IDEAS", "CREDITS_AND_REFERENCES"];
  for (var i in topic_list) {
    var element = document.createElement("h6");
    var node = document.createTextNode(topic_list[i]);
    $(element).append(node);
    $(header).append(element);
    element.className = "topics";
    element.id = topic_list_id[i];
  }
});
```

```css
h6:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

h6 {
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <div id="hover">
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a pure css solution? or do you have to use javascript?

> **Pure CSS solution**

```css
#hover:hover {
  background: grey;
}
      
#hover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: background 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id = "header">
  <div id = "hover">
    <h6>WHAT IS A HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARD?"</h6>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: because I want to make it fade rather than just showing up

Comment: You can also **fade** in **CSS**. I edited my solution and added a transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using css and applying styles of `topics` class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topic_list = ["WHAT IS A HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL BIOHAZARD?", "NATURAL DISASTERS", "OUR IDEAS", "CREDITS AND REFERENCES"];
  var topic_list_id = ["WHAT_IS_A_HYDROMETEOROLOGICAL_BIOHAZARD", "NATURAL_DISASTERS", "OUR_IDEAS", "CREDITS_AND_REFERENCES"];
  for (var i in topic_list) {
    var element = document.createElement("h6");
    var node = document.createTextNode(topic_list[i]);
    $(element).append(node);
    $(header).append(element);
    element.className = "topics";
    element.id = topic_list_id[i];
  }


});
```

```css
.topics {
  padding: 20px;
}

.topics:hover {
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0.25;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <div id="hover">
  </div>
</header>
```